# apache proxying subdir to rails app

Tags: apache, proxy, passenger, config, subdirectory

I would like to run a rails application (redmine, actually) in a subdirectory off my domain. SOmething like http://foobar.com/redmine. Redmine is running as a stand-alone passenger instance that I would like to proxy requests to.

```
passenger start -a 127.0.0.1 -p 8000 -e production
```

I can confirm that the app is running if I access it locally from the server.

```
lynx http://127.0.0.1:8000/
```

Now I can't figure out how to get Apache to serve the app properly. This is what I have, but it doesn't work quite right:

```
Alias /redmine /home/redmine/www/redmine-1.2/public
<Directory /home/redmine/www/redmine-1.2/public>
  allow from all
  ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:8000
  ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8000
</Directory>
```

It serves static assets fine from the public folder but doesn't seem to proxy requests properly. Everything returns 403. Apache log:

```
client denied by server configuration: proxy:http://127.0.0.1:8000
```

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out. Apache config:

```
<Location /redmine>
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
  ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:8000
  ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8000
</Location>
```

Then add this line to config/environment.rb:

```
config.action_controller.relative_url_root = "/redmine"
```